# I cannot update my Date column? error: datatruncation

Tags: java, sql

mySQL datatype for column "LOGINDATE" is Date. Why do i get this error?

```
private void compareDate(){
    sql = "Select curdate()";
    Date currentDate = lastLogin;
    try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            currentDate = rs.getDate(1);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    if(currentDate.compareTo(lastLogin) == 1){
        System.out.println(currentDate);
        System.out.println(lastLogin);
        sql = "UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET LOGINDATE="+currentDate+", NFLIXCREDIT=3 WHERE USERNAME='"+username+"'";
        try{
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

2015-05-30

2015-05-29

Error -

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date
>   value: '1980' for column 'LOGINDATE' at row 1

Comment: Your SQL is evaluated to `UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET LOGINDATE=2015-05-30, NFLIXCREDIT=3...`.  And `2015-05-30` is evaluated to `1980`.  You should use PreparedStatement instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is not prepared Statement.

Change to

```
   sql = "UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET LOGINDATE=?, NFLIXCREDIT=3 WHERE USERNAME=?";
    try{
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDate(1,currentDate);
        ps.setString(2,username);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException e){
```

in your case the `toString()` method of date will be called and then your date is to long

Answer (score 0):

Using a prepared Statement is the best option.

Another option is to wrap the date with ' ':

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET LOGINDATE='2015-05-30', NFLIXCREDIT=3...
```